# using '.' when passing parameters to java binary with -D does not parse well

Tags: java, linux, hudson, jenkins

I am using Jenkins CI to run java from `execute shell` build step :

`java -jar -Dadmin.hostname=$hostname -Dschema_name=$schema myapp.jar`

I have noticed that although both parameters `hostname` and `schema` are defined well and has non empty values on runtime, Jenkins parses it the following way:

`java -jar -Dadmin.hostname= -Dschema_name=MYDB myapp.jar`

meaning `admin.hostname` value doesn't get parsed.

I have tracked the problem and noticed that when i dont use `.` in the parameter name everything get parsed okay.

I am wondering if this is a limitation of Java command line or a bug in Jenkins perhaps. (I am using RHEL64)

Thanks

EDIT:
I think this is bug with Parametrized build jenkins plugin as using `.` in other builds works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that environment variables on UNIX are case sensitive

```
$ echo $hostname

$ echo $HOSTNAME
myhostname
```

There shouldn't be any problem using `.` because may built in properties uses them.

BTW: Just because a property is set to blank doesn't mean its not set.

```
System.out.println("not.set=" + System.getProperty("not.set"));
System.out.println("admin.hostname='" + System.getProperty("admin.hostname")+"'");
```

when run with `-Dadmin.hostname=` prints

```
not.set=null
admin.hostname=''
```

Comment: I have checked the case sensitivity and it doesnt seem to be the problem. this is a weird behaviour since it only happen when i use variables set with the Parameterized Build plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: There was no problem after all, my variable was overriden and made me think that it was a problem with the name. Stupid me, Thank you anyway